# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS and DDS

Tags: ros, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I'm thinking about tu make ROS publisher node, which publish to the DDS. Do you have any advices, tutorials? Which DDS open source implementation I should use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209269/ros-and-dds/) by [miltas](https://answers.ros.org/users/22436/miltas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understand it, ROS2 is built on DDS. You should have a look. http://design.ros2.org/

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2